# Which Authorization grant type to use for requesting access token from IdentityServer3 with Integrated windows authentication?

Tags: windows-authentication, identityserver3

I'm doing a design for an intranet application by which the intranet web application invokes web API using access token issued by IdentityServer3. As it is an intranet application, I will go for IdentityServer3 with Windows authentication. 
As user is involved, I believe **Resource owner password credential flow** is the way to request for token from IdentityServer3. How to use this flow with integrated windows authentication? i.e., I wont be having logged in user password

Thanks,
Cellv

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Resource Owner Password Credential Flow, as the name suggests, expects you to provide a username & password.

You'll need to use a different flow, as you're not using passwords, such as implicit flow.